# Why Custom Dimension with "user" scope level doesn't show up in my report?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

This question is related with my previous question here: 
[What is the difference between Hit, Session, and User level in Google Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831402/what-is-the-difference-between-hit-session-and-user-level-in-google-analytics)

So, I tried to set the custom dimension to User level scope, but the data still show 0 view. Since the report is not real time, I waited for 2 days, but still data remained 0. But when I changed it to session level scope, on the next day, the data started showing up.

The use case that I want to track is must be set to user level scope, but I don't know what is wrong. 
Something I miss?

Comment: Can you share the site?

Comment: @Blexy: Not for website, but I implemented it in my game on ios and android.

Comment: Is the custom dim state set to "active" in GA admin? Just checking...

Comment: @Drewdavid yes I set it to active

Comment: Any news on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need a user level scope? If the user can switch his character type during a session a user level dimension will not reflect any state of the world.

There could be a number of when using dimension widening (custom dimensions and metrics) issues here is a checklist:

- Configuration

  - Are you working with universal analytics?
  - Are you have a app reporting view?
  - What is the name of the custom dimension you are using.
  - Are you using Google analytics SDKs v2.x or higher
  - Is the custom dimension activity state set to true (if it's false you will have the dimension in reports/segments but no data).
  - How many dimensions are you tracking?
- Collection

  - when are you sending the custom dimension
  - what does your code snippet look like ?
  - is the analytics data being buffered ?
  - are you sending all the analytics data?
  - are you exceeding session collection limits?
- Processing

  - Do your views have filters interfering with display of custom dimensions. *(development/testing IP disabled where the custom data is displayed)*
- Reporting

  - Changing the scope of the custom dimensions will not reprocess the data - you will see results that are not accurate. So you will have to restrict the dates to a period for just the scope

Finally in real life there is also (cross device) user level tracking via the useId feature with its own configuration/collection/processing/reporting that will affect the sessionization schema and a misconfiguration would affect collection of user level data.